# listview item indexing

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, paging, listviewitem

I am using a listview with 6 items per page. When I choose an item from the 6 items it should take me to a page with 3 items per page BUT the selected item (on previous page) as FIRST item in the list on the new page. Basically how do I set which items shows first in the listview? Is that a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property for setting the first item.  If you are using a datasource, the items will be displayed in the order they occur in the datasource, which is generally the order that the database returns them.

If you need a different ordering, you can code a loop through your datasource and assign the items to the ListView manually.

Comment: thanks Jason. I just wanted to know if this could be done easily by setting a publis property /method for a listview.